# Divs on border design conflicts with fixed background

Tags: html, css

I have an issue regarding a conflict between this content border frame (`.inner`) and the body background fixed image.

On the title and some div classes I am using background to hide the border and create an illusion of a non-complete border where the title and some is placed.

When adding a fixed background this does not work anymore as you can tell - for the title and some div, when adding `background: transparent;` the border becomes visible. How can I keep this border content design (`.inner`) and still have a fixed background, while not having to use another div background color or having to display the border underneath the some and title divs.

```css
body {
  background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/956999/milky-way-starry-sky-night-sky-star-956999.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260");
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1.title {
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  background: blue;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: -40px auto 0 auto;
}

div.inner {
  border: 4px solid red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 50px 50px 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

div.some {
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  /*background: transparent; */
  max-width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto -60px auto;
  position: relative;
}

div.some::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-right: 5px solid red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

div.some::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  float: right;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">


  <h1 class="title">Hello World</h1>


  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <br>
  
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <br>
  
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <br>


  <div class="some"> SoMe

  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: look at this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790675/make-part-of-div-border-transparent-html

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! This is how I solved it: https://jsfiddle.net/hye16wuL/